# add product url to the product name in sales/order/view page

Tags: magento2

File: `app/code/Anshu/OrderItemLink/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_items">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="plink" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Link</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
            <referenceBlock name="default_order_items_renderer">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="plink" xsi:type="string" translate="false">product-link</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn" name="column_plink" template="Anshu_OrderItemLink::item_link.phtml" group="column" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

File: `app/code/Anshu/OrderItemLink/view/adminhtml/templates/item_link.phtml`

```
<?php if ($_item = $block->getItem()): ?>
    <div class="product-link-block">
        <a href="<?= $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl() ?>" target="_blank"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Link to Product')) ?></a>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

i tried this but i will gives url with another column 'product link'

Comment: Hello Mani, please add more details in your question in order to get proper response.

Comment: hello Rajeev, i am completely new to magento. i  want make product name as link in admin/sales/order/view page i.e, when i click on the link it will redirect to product url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to modify anything to product name then you need to overide this block into your extension.

```
 <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name" name="column_name" template="Magento_Sales::items/column/name.phtml" group="column"/>
```

This `Block` class and `template` show the Product Name column there.

Comment: thanks dhiren vasoya

Comment: If answer help. please upvote and accept as solution, so it will help other in community.

Answer (score 0):

```
for making product name as url in admin/sales/order view page i done this.
```

```
file: app\code\Manoj\Productlink\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_view.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="column_name">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Manoj_Productlink::items/column/name.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

```
file : app\code\Manoj\Productlink\view\adminhtml\templates\items\column\name.phtml
```

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

?>
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer
 */
?>

<?php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogHelper */
$catalogHelper = $block->getData('catalogHelper');
?>
<?php if ($_item = $block->getItem()): ?>
    <div id="order_item_<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>_title"
         class="product-title">
         <a href="<?= $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl() ?>" target="_blank"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="product-sku-block">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('SKU'))?>:</span>
        <?= /* @noEscape */ implode('<br />', $catalogHelper->splitSku($block->escapeHtml($block->getSku()))) ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ($block->getOrderOptions()): ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getOrderOptions() as $_option): ?>
                <dt><?= $block->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?>:</dt>
                <dd>
                    <?php if (isset($_option['custom_view']) && $_option['custom_view']): ?>
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getCustomizedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php $_option = $block->getFormattedOption($_option['value']); ?>
                        <?php $dots = 'dots' . uniqid(); ?>
                        <?php $id = 'id' . uniqid(); ?>
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_option['value'], ['a', 'br']) ?>
                        <?php if (isset($_option['remainder']) && $_option['remainder']): ?>
                            <span id="<?= /* @noEscape */ $dots; ?>"> ...</span>
                            <span id="<?= /* @noEscape */ $id; ?>">
                                <?= $block->escapeHtml($_option['remainder'], ['a']) ?>
                            </span>
                            <?php $scriptString = <<<script
                                require(['prototype'], function() {

script;
                            $scriptString .= "$('" . /* @noEscape */ $id . "').hide();" . PHP_EOL;
                            $scriptString .= "$('" . /* @noEscape */ $id .
                             "').up().observe('mouseover', function(){ $('" . /* @noEscape */ $id . "').show();});" .
                              PHP_EOL;
                            $scriptString .= "$('" . /* @noEscape */ $id .
                                "').up().observe('mouseover', function(){ $('" . /* @noEscape */ $dots .
                                 "').hide();});" . PHP_EOL;
                            $scriptString .= "$('" . /* @noEscape */ $id .
                                "').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){ $('" . /* @noEscape */ $id .
                                 "').hide();});" . PHP_EOL;
                            $scriptString .= "$('" . /* @noEscape */ $id .
                                "').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){ $('" . /* @noEscape */ $dots .
                                 "').show();});" . PHP_EOL . "});" . PHP_EOL;
                            ?>
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', [], $scriptString, false) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

```
file : app\code\Manoj\Productlink\etc\module.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Manoj_Productlink">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

```
file :app\code\Manoj\Productlink\registration.php
```

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Manoj_Productlink',
    __DIR__
);
```

```
 <a href="<?= $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl() ?>" target="_blank"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
```

```
i added above line in name.phtml to make product name as url
```

```
pls correct me if i'm worng
```